Best way to install a ceiling fan with a surface-mounted junction box
I am buying an apartment where a previous owner added a chandelier using a surface-mounted ceiling junction box and surface-mounted conduit (in other words, nothing is inside the ceiling.)  I'd like to put a fan there.  I had something similar done in my current place, and there is a gap between the fan mount and the ceiling.  It has never bothered me overmuch, but I'd like to avoid the same in the new place.
Are there low-profile ceiling junction boxes that would allow a fan or light housing to be flush with the ceiling?  Or is there some other way that people typically cover that gap?
Any help is appreciated!

Is there a joist above (behind) the box that the fan can be mounted to?

Got any pictures?

@ThreePhaseEel - I don't know if there is a joist.  It's a high-rise apartment complex built in the 1950's.  Once I've closed on the apartment, I can ask the building management these questions.

@RSKadish oh, that's going to make things interesting.  We'll need photos for sure to determine what sort of floor-ceiling assembly is present

Light fixtures don't vibrate. Fans do, as well as tending to be heavier. Fans require much more secure mounting. I would expect that few, if any, surface boxes are rated for this application. Use a floor fan or install a box that can survive this use.

I'm not sure why I can't respond to the previous answer, or comment on the post, but at any rate - The 50" ceiling fan in my bedroom was installed fifteen years ago by an electrician using a surface box. There's never been any problem.

@RSKadish: The implied word is "yet"... The big question is how the surface box is affixed to the ceiling. And there are things we do (like the anchor cable) which we certainly hope are never needed short of an earthquake or tornado but which are good practice anyway.
